# How to hide cart in header navigation for logged out user with WordPress and WooCommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide the cart (see image) for logged out users. How might I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on where the code that renders your cart is in the theme's code. Here is an example of what I would do:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>

  Cart Code Goes Here

<?php endif; ?>
```

Where the Cart Code would be the code that renders the cart in the image you provided. If you can show a snippet of where that cart code is I can be more accurate with my answer.

Koda

Comment: Hey. Thanks. It's in the [Storefront theme](https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/?_ga=2.232350367.164184355.1505046250-1006376747.1504905241), I believe the `site-header-cart` ID.

Comment: As I said in my post please find the file that needs editing, include it in your question and I'll show you where to edit.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I've spent about an hour looking and can't find what I'm looking for. I see a bunch of hooks but not the source of the element after I inspect it. I'm not sure where I'd plug in the code you provided yet but I'll keep looking!

Comment: Feel free to take your time, I will revisit once you are ready.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I appreciate your help. I'm marking this as solved as it does do exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add to your functions.php file

```
add_action('init', 'bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in');

function bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',     'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );  
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 31 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 11 );
    }
}

function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' .  __('Login to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the OP as I think this is great for hiding stuff whilst not logged in but does not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with simple CSS. First you'll need to find the class you want to hide when logged out. You can do this by right clicking the cart icon and inspect element. Now that you have the class you can add this CSS to your additional CSS in customize or to your style.css file.

```
body:not(.logged-in) .nav-link-cart {
  display: none !important;
}
```

The above is an example with my class added to the css. In this case my class is "nav-link-cart".

Simply replace "nav-link-cart" with your own class. Easy work :)